# issue with jQuery toggle()

Tags: jquery

I have an issue with jQuery `.toggle()`

I connected the button button to a div with jQuery, but it doesn't work

I tried some javascript `document.style.visibility="hidden"`

When I click on the button, it should open or close the div

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#show").click(function() {
    $("#prout").toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="prout" class="fichier1">
  <div class="droite1">droite</div>
  <div class="gauche1">gauche</div>
</div>
<button id="show" class="btna poz2">arme 2</button>
```

Comment: jQuery won't show div with `visibility:hidden`. It'll work on divs with `display:none`

Comment: @mplungjan am I missed something? I think the JS code should be outside of the code block.

Comment: What does `click on the ,is ton a div` mean, zyace?

Comment: my mistake , i want to click on button to open div

Comment: So hide it first `$(document).ready(function() { $("#prout").hide(); ...` or use `#prout { display:none}` in a stylesheet

Comment: @mplungjan ah I tried to leave only 3 dots and wrap in code. Backspace malfunctioned

Comment: i have 21 button

Comment: Give them a class and have `.toHide { display:none}`

Comment: can you me  show the code ? ple

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a class and display:none to toggle

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".show").click(function() {
    $(this).prev().toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.fichier {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="prout" class="fichier">
  <div class="droite1">droite</div>
  <div class="gauche1">gauche</div>
</div>
<button class="show btna poz2">arme 1</button>
<hr/>
<div id="prout1" class="fichier">
  <div class="droite1">droite</div>
  <div class="gauche1">gauche</div>
</div>
<button class="show btna poz2">arme 2</button>
```